# No table in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, user-controls

i want to bind 3 string data to table in wp8 but idont know how to do that.

the problem is :-
i get response from the server then i desrlaized this response to string's for example string a, string b , string c
i want to display them on the screen of the phone as row then when i got the second response i want to bind them in new line like the old string (Keep the old row)...... to get full table

please help me i have tried sample like this but there in no data appeared on the phone screen :-

```
Grid Layout = new Grid();
Layout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = GridLength.Auto });
Layout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(50) });
Layout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(50) });
Layout.Children.Add(new TextBlock() { });
//Read the children
foreach (UIElement element in Layout.Children)
{
    //Read it's row and column property
    int row = (int)element.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
}
//Some logic to store the row-columns of the UIElement, if required

//Then bind some data by retrieving the TextBlock
TextBlock lbl = Layout.Children[0] as TextBlock;
Binding bind = new Binding();
//logic for binding
lbl.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bind);
```

Comment: I've returned to the original question as it better describes the problem than further edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are couple of things why your code doesn't work:

- you are not setting Column for your TextBlocks - Grid.SetColumn()
- you are creating Grid, but you aren't adding it to to any StackPanel or ListBox which are visible on the screen
- I'm not sure what you have tried to achieve within foreach loop
- it is hard to tell what you 'logic for binding' does

In this case it is simpler to use a ListBox:

In XAML, in your Page:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
   <ListBox Name="myList">
       <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
               <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
           </Style>
       </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding textFirst}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding textSecond}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding textThird}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
               </Grid>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

In code behind - you just then declare ObservableCollection for items and set it as ItemsSource of ListBox. You need also to create a class with your data:

```
public class Data
{
    public string textFirst { get; set; }
    public string textSecond { get; set; }
    public string textThird { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    ObservableCollection<Data> dataReceived = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myList.ItemsSource = dataReceived;
        // and to add data you do it like this:
       dataReceived.Add(new Data() { textFirst = "First text", textSecond = "Second Text", textThird = "Third one" });
    }
 }
```

Comment: sorry friend its not work, the error on <Data>, i have update my question with the code i need to bind please advise...

Comment: @user3451041 What kind of error? (probably you haven't added namespace for ObservaleCollection - then add `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` among other usings). If you get this working then you can easily put your data into 3 column table.

Comment: @user3451041 So what the error says? Can you just try to build a very simple app only with the ListBox I've posted - see how it works?

Comment: I have tried it gave me errors , please do you have another scenario

Comment: @user3451041 Still - can you tell what kind of errors do you get?

Comment: the error appeared on <Data> and this is the error   ************ Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\mohammad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\PhoneApp6\PhoneApp6\MainPage.xaml.cs 327 34 PhoneApp6

Comment: @user3451041 Have you added the class Data as in the code above? Outside your MainPage constructor?

Comment: @user3451041 I've edited a little code - try to create new project, copy and paste above code to xaml i cs files, try to run. I've completely no idea what is wrong in your code - this is very basic example it should work without issue. Unfortunately I don't have teamviewer.

Comment: Thank you Romasz its working fine after i have restarted my laptop , i dont know what was the problem .....